# Angular & Jasmine: how to inject services with dots in their names

Tags: angularjs, testing

I've got a service that's defined this way:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .factory("myService.foo", function () {
    // utterly delightful code
  });
```

I'm using Karma and Jasmine for testing.  In the test, I am doing something like this for most of my server tests:

```
describe('Service: someService', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var _someService;
  beforeEach(inject([function (someService) {
    _someService = someService;
  }]));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(!!_someService).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

When I try to do the same with a service named something like "myService.foo" it throws an error (of course):

```
describe('Service: myService.foo', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var _myService;
  beforeEach(inject([function (myService.foo) {
    _myService = myService.foo;
  }]));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(!!_myService).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Because of the obvious problem with the dot syntax making angular unable to infer the service name.  How can I inject this service to test it?  Is there some alternate syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the array notation, for example:

```
var _myService;
beforeEach(inject(['myService.foo', function (myService) {
    _myService = myService;
}]));
```

Note (from [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.managing_dependencies)):

> It is important that the order of the string identifiers in the array
>   is the same as the order of argument names in the signature of the
>   factory function. Unless the dependencies are inferred from the
>   function signature, it is this array with IDs and their order that the
>   injector uses to determine which services and in which order to
>   inject.